# Restrain div to bottom of browser window

Tags: css, html

I have a layout like the following:

[image]

Now what I would like if for the "Content" part to stretch to the bottom of the browser window, but not any further. Any overflow should by handled by a scrollbar on the "Content" part. I have tried position: fixed, but couldn't quite seem to make it work.

Of course, frames are not an option, but I don't have to please IE6 (yay!).

Comment: Is everything a fixed width/height with the exception that elements have to stretch to the edges?

Comment: @thirtydot Gah, sorry! The toolbar is 100% wide, but it's not always there. The info column is fixed width. The tabs have the same width as the content, and variable height.

Comment: Could you please post your html and css. It would also be useful if you could create a http://jsfiddle.net.

Comment: Does the info column also `stretch[es] to the bottom of the browser window, but not any further` ?

Comment: The info column should also just stretch to the bottom of the window, and then scroll the rest of the content. @tw16, Basic setup is here: http://jsfiddle.net/manisto/f5Tfz/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an example that seems to work - http://jsfiddle.net/JQW2c/3/

```
<div class="toolbar">Toolbar</div>
<div class="info">info</div>
<div class="contentContainer">
    <div class="tabs">tabs</div>
    <div class="content">content</div>
</div>

body, html
{
   font-family: Arial;
   margin: 0px;
   padding: 0px; 
   height: 100%;
}

div.toolbar
{
   background-color: #EB526C;
   height: 50px;
}
div.tabs
{
   background-color: #75D17B;
   margin-right:100px; 
   height: 30px;  
}
div.info
{
   background-color: #E2F285;
   width: 100px;
   position: absolute;
   top: 50px;
   bottom: 0px;
   right: 0px;
}
div.content
{
   background-color: #7794ED;
   position: absolute;
   top: 80px;
   bottom: 0px;
   left: 0px;
   right: 100px;
   overflow: auto;
}
```

Comment: This works, but I do not know the exact height of the tabs! :(

Comment: If there are only 2-3 options for the tabs status, you could add an additional class to the content div in order to set different top values.
If the tabs height is completely dynamic and unpredictable, you may have to modify the top style of the content using javascript.

Comment: You should be using `position: absolute` instead of `position: fixed`.

Comment: @thirtydot - shouldn't really matter in this specific scenario.

Comment: @Amit, the height is unpredictable. I guess I have to resort to using JavaScript, although I'm not fond of using scripting for layout. But in this senario, it seems the only way.

Comment: @Amit: It could matter for small reasons. It needlessly breaks IE6 - I know it was said that support isn't required, but why break it for no reason? A more important reason is if you want to set a `min-width` or `min-height` (which is a sensible thing to do with these type of layouts), see: http://jsfiddle.net/thirtydot/JQW2c/5/. Change `absolute` to `fixed`, then make the window small, and scroll left or down.

Comment: @thirtydot - fair enough, a scenario with a `min-height` for the content and a scroll for the whole window once it is very small is a reasonable one. I'll changed to `absolute` then.

Answer (score 0):

Give this a go...

```
`#content {height:100%; overflow:scroll;}`
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work, but depending on the actual setup you have and/or the interaction, it might not :)

```
#content { position: absolute; top: toolbarheight + tabsheight; left: 0; right: infocolumnwidth; bottom: 0; overflow: auto;}
```

You’re most probably going to need to set the top position value with JS.